# Why this infinite loop does not consume 100% CPU

Tags: c#, .net, infinite-loop

I was pretty sure that infinite loops consume 100% CPU. Why the following loop does not? (The task manager shows 0%)

```
do
{
    // Do something
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: `ReadKey()` blocks. This is not a busy loop.

Comment: In addition, true infinite loops (tend to) consume 100% of a single CPU *thread*. You could have anywhere from one to twelve of those. If you're running Windows (C#, so you probably are), number of hardware threads == number of nodes in Device Manager's "Processors" node.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the loop and discover why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Console.ReadKey` blocks on the issuing thread until the user presses a key.  A `while(true)` loop executes continuously and consumes as much CPU as the OS will allow.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx